# Redirect removing sufixes after 3 URL segmentes in Nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect, redirection

This is the URL that I need to remove the last segment `(?order=asc)`

```
https://www.example.com/segment_1/segment_2/page/the_number_goes_here/?order?asc
```

**This is the code I'm trying:**

```
location ~ ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/page/(\d+)/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    # Capture the 2 segments and page number
    set $segment_1 $1;
    set $segment_2 $2;
    set $page_number $4;
    # Redirect without the sufix
    rewrite ^ /$segment_1/$segment_2/page/$page_number/ permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `location` and `rewrite` directives process the [normalised URI](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) which does not include the query string (which you have called "the last segment").

The query string is available in the `$args` variable.

The [`rewrite` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) can optionally remove the original query string by appending a `?` to the end of the replacement value.

For example:

```
rewrite ^ /$segment_1/$segment_2/page/$page_number/? permanent;
```

---

Also, in your example code:

- The page number is captured in `$3` and not `$4`
- The `try_files` statement is probably redundant as Nginx will always evaluate the `set` and `rewrite` directives first.

is evaluated first